# Symfony2, unable to find file after deployment

Tags: javascript, symfony

after deploying my project on the live server i'm getting this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Unable to find file "@JDareClankBundle/Resources/public/js/".") in "JDareClankBundle::client.html.twig".
```

Cleared the cache, dumped the assets ....

I don't get this error on my local machine ... don't know what's wrong.

Any idea?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. check if your configs are the same on dev and production
2. check if app/AppKernel.php is the same on dev and production
3. check if that file exists on production
4. clear cache manualy: `rm -rf app/cache/*` then install assets using `app/console assets:install --env=prod` and then dump them using `app/console assetic:dump --env=prod`

do third step also on your local machine using parameter --env=prod to see if you get that error

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough i removed the {javascript} part from the client.html.twig of clank, cleared the cache, readded it ...and now it's working. Really weird.